# Multiple Cluster Kafka Setup

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to setup a multiple kafka cluster with around 3 zookeeper instance, with 3 kafka brokers in each cluster and each kafka broker with around 5 topics and 5 partitions. Is there any setup guide i can refer to?

PS: i can find information for a Single zookeeper instance with multiple Kafka brokers, but not the setups with multiple zookeeper instances.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a beginner's guide, but we found the [Apache Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) contains all answers to questions you might have. In general, we experienced the Kafka set up process painless.

The amount of Zookeeper instances should be odd and >= 3. With 1 Zookeeper instance you have a single point of failure.

By the way, 5 partitions per topic seems quite low. You can always increase the number of partitions. A higher number of partitions enables using more consumers, but also requires more memory usage of the consumer processes, because consumers buffer a certain number of Kafka messages per partition they own. For reference, we use have a similar setup and we use 60 partitions per topic.